# On stack deploy, unable to pin image to digest: unauthorized: the client does not have permission for manifest

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-swarm, docker-stack

I'm running a Docker stack using a custom image which I have pushed to an Artifactory repository.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    image: repo.example.com/my_image:latest
```

I can pull the image fine, and I can deploy the stack fine, but if I try to redeploy the stack, I get an error.

```
$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml my_stack
Creating network my_stack_default
Creating service my_stack_app

$ docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml my_stack
Updating service my_stack_app (id: 8po6oepjdgo8kwsb7n4ig64dt)
unable to pin image repo.example.com/my_image:latest to digest: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest
```

I expect Docker to update the image when I redeploy the stack, just like it would if I used an image from Docker Hub.

I've seen Docker say `unable to pin image` before, but that was when I did not specify a repository (e.g. docker.io).  I know I have permission from `repo.example.com` because I pushed the image there, I can still pull from it, and I can start the stack.  I just can't update it.

What does this `client does not have permission for manifest` error mean, and how do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was we were using a specific old version of Docker Swarm (I think version 13) that had a bug that caused this error.  We were limited to that version since RHEL7 at the time was limited to that version.  Using Ubuntu and updating Docker to a more recent version solved it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have all of your permissions approved then the issue may be that your local `.docker\config.json` file has not been created.

If that is the case then you may want to run this command in the terminal at the root of your folder:

```bash
docker login repo.example.com
```

That will take your credentials and store them in an unencrypted `.docker\config.json` file.

After that your deploy should work (and you might want to consider configuring a credential helper to keep your credentials safe).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31990010)

Comment: This was the problem in my case

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your user does not have the "Delete / Overwrite" permission to this repository. Please ask your Artifactory admin to add this permission to your user for this repository and try again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. I already have Delete/Overwrite permissions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would not having Delete/Overwrite permissions cause issues?